# Transactions handling in System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, system.data.sqlite

I have a problem with understanding transactions handling in System.Data.Sqlite connected with the following piece of code.

```
public static string ConnenctionString = "Data Source=C:\\DB\\Test.db";

public static void Test1()
{
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnenctionString);
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        string sql = $"insert into table1 (id) values ({i})";

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    transaction.Commit();

}
public static void Test2()
{
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnenctionString);
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "select count(*) from table1";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
}
public static void Test3()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnenctionString);
        connection.Open();
        SQLiteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        string sql = $"insert into table1 (id) values ({i})";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Everything is ok

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test1());
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test2());

    //Exception db is locked
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test3());
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test2());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In one task I am executing some long running operation (in one transaction) - method `Test1`. In second task, I am trying to execute another query, without transaction - method `Test2`. Everything is running OK, I obtain a result that doesn't include changes from `Test1` - because transaction hasn't been commited yet.

But when trying to execute in one task lots of queries - each in separate transaction, like in method `Test3` and trying meanwhile to execute method `Test2`, I am obtaing exception: DB is locked. Is there a way to omit such behaviour modyfing connection string?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using **[using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)** statements (unfortunate pun):

```
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("conn-string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string sql = $"insert into table1 (id) values ({i})";

            using (var command = new SqliteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: there may be more optimal ways to do bulk inserts like a stored proc if you have massive amounts of data.  however the `using` block or statement takes care of the disposing of resources like connections strings and commands thus preventing memory leaks or locked resources.

Comment: It is possible to implement proper `using` code AND reuse the `SqliteCommand` object also.  You can create a command object in a using statement, but ensure that the SQL text has parameters.  Add formal parameter objects inside the using statement.  Then within the loop, set the parameters, execute the command, then call `command.Reset()` so that it can be used again.  `System.Data.SQLite.SqliteCommand` automatically compiles and retains the statement for reuse, so the code above takes minimal changes to efficiently handle bulk inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify your database so it will use [write-ahead logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). It will allow simultaneous access for multiple tasks without locking.

```
ExecuteQuery("pragma journal_mode=WAL");
```

immediately after creating the database. You need to execute this statement only once - it's persistent.